# How to add mysql Trigger?

Tags: mysql

I need trigger to add current date (only date not time) on every insert in my table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_created_date
BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.created_date = date();
END;
```

this is my code. what am i doing in wrong? thank you

Comment: If you use BEGIN END, then you need to use `DELIMITER` to change the delimiter so the `;`'s in the body don't "end" the trigger definition early

Comment: Hello there, it seems that your problem was solved, please mark the answer you find most useful to your problem as accepted one. You do so by clicking in the V icon in the left side of your chosen answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution:

```
USE db_name; -- or select the database with script / tool

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER set_created_date BEFORE INSERT ON people 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.created_date = CURDATE(); 
END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

---

**notes / explanation:**

- You need to use `DELIMITER` so MySQL can handle the `;` correctly.
- The [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function extracts the date part of a datetime value.
- You want to set the current date so you can use [`CURDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) or `DATE(NOW())`.

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e96B65hDocUBpNgobXaHiK/0

---

**Difference between this [`TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and a column [`DEFAULT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):**

In case you are using a `DEFAULT` value on the column `created_date` the default value is only set to the column if no value is provided for this column on `INSERT`. So if someone run a `INSERT` command like the following:

```
INSERT INTO people (name, created_date) VALUES ('John Doe', '2017-02-03');
```

the default value (the current date) is not set to the column. Instead the available value will be set to the column (`2017-02-03`).

The `TRIGGER` set the current date on every `INSERT`. If someone execute the above `INSERT` command still the current date will be set to the `created_date` column (not the value provided on the `INSERT` command).

Comment: Running this I am getting error : > 1046 - No database selected. table "people" exists.

Comment: you need to select a database on the script or tool you are using (connect to the databse). you can also use `USE` to select a database on the mysql script. and make sure the table `people` exists before the `CREATE TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 1):

Why a trigger? Why not set your `create_date` field `default now()`

```
 alter table people modify column create_date datetime default now();
```

Here it is showing how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50a441/1

Comment: Or `CURDATE()` :)

Comment: what is happening if someone use the following: `INSERT INTO people (name, created_date) VALUES ('somename', '2017-05-24')`? - *I need trigger to add current date (only date not time) on **every insert** in my table*

Comment: @SebastianBrosch That is another approach instead of a trigger, an easier one. You control your system, if the database is used by multiple users make sure they are aware of this rule and don't use the insert passing the date. To date only just set your field as date and it is fine.